# Is it possible to calculate $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations

I am struggling with this.

If $p=\frac{(x+y)}{2}$ and $q=\frac{y}{x}$ and you know the values for $p$ and $q$, can you calculate what $x$ and $y$ are?

I tried $p=3.5$ and $q=2.5$ as an example. Given this $p$ and $q$, is the only possible solution $x=2$ and $y=5$? Or are there other solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: $$x= \dfrac{2 p}{q+1},y = 2 p-\dfrac{2 p}{q+1}$$

Comment: You have $y=qx$ which you can insert in $p=(x+y)/2$. But note $x\ne 0$

Comment: @Moo  Terrific! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = q x$ so your first equation becomes $p = \frac{1+q}{2} x$, therefore (assuming $q \ne -1$) the only solution is
$$ x = \frac{2p}{1+q},\ y = \frac{2qp}{1+q}$$
where we need $p \ne 0$.

Second case: $1+q = 0$.  Then if $p \ne 0$, there is no solution, while if $p = 0$ the first equation becomes $0=0$ the solutions are $y=-x$, $x=$ anything except $0$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)